# How to replace substring as a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, string

```
$arr['CONST_A'] = 'D:\A';
$arr['CONST_A_B'] = 'D:\A\B';
```

`convert('D:\A\B\C', $arr)` should output `CONST_A_B . '\C'`

How to implement such a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a litte cumbersome. It sorts the const array by string length, so it finds the longest possibilities first. Then it compares each string, and on a hit finds the original constant name.

```
function convert($str, $arr) {
    $search = array_combine($arr, array_map("strlen", $arr));
    arsort($search);
    foreach ($search as $part=>$len) {
       if (strncmp($str, $part, $len) == 0) {
           $const = array_search($part, $arr);
           return "$const . '" . substr($str, $len) . "'";
       }
    }
}
```